# Place price in a label that updates when the user changes it's value

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have the following problem.

Im making a form in which the user can select some products they would like to order.
This looks like this:

`<input type="number" class="bestelformulier" name="PizzaMagarita" onkeyup="validateForm(this)" min="1" max="999">`

Only i have 11 fields.

And the user can place a desired number in this input field and click submit to go to the confimation page.

But that's not what this is about. I'd like to make it so, that if the user types a 1 it would show the price next to the Pizza saying € 7,00. But when he desides he wants 2, and places a 2 in the input field the price would actually change to € 14,00.

I got the label and table in place so everything that needs to be done is the code itself, where it looks for the value in the input field of the pizza and takes it * 7 and places that in the Label.

I don't know if im wanting to much right now, since im not really familiar with PHP and JS but im eager to learn so any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

My validateForm() function is used so only 1 of the 11 fields has to be filled in to continue but when none is filled in the button is disabled:

```
function validateForm()
    {
        var allEmpty = (document.forms['form'].PizzaMagarita.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['form'].PizzaFungi.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['form'].PizzaHawai.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['form'].PizzaQuattroStagioni.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['form'].PizzaCalzone.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['form'].BroodjeShoarma.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['form'].BroodjeDoner.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['form'].DurumDoner.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['form'].KnoflookSaus.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['form'].WhiskeySaus.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['form'].SambalSaus.value == "");

        if(allEmpty)
        {
            document.forms[0].submit.disabled=true;
        }
        else {  
            document.forms[0].submit.disabled=false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `validateForm()` function?

Comment: A code that updates prices based on selected or input quantities is a very common one. It uses mainly **javascript** and **ajax**.  ,<br />  You can create a script that manages the **DOM** elements to update the final value or basket value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a the price on the client side, you could listen for a change event on the input, then calculate, format and display the price.

Assuming your html looks something like this:

```
<input type="number" id="pizzaCount" class="bestelformulier" name="PizzaMagarita" onkeyup="validateForm(this)" min="1" max="999">
<h3>Total Price</h3>
<span id="totalPrice">$0.00</span>
```

And you're not using jQuery... you would want to grab a reference to the input, attach a change event listener, then update the label when value of the input changes.

```
var pizzaPrice = 7;
var numPizzaInput = document.getElementById('pizzaCount');
var priceLabel    = document.getElementById('totalPrice');

function onNumPizzaInputChange(e){

    var totalPrice = pizzaPrice * parseInt(e.target.value);
    var formattedPrice = '$'+totalPrice.toFixed(2);

    priceLabel.innerHTML = '';
    priceLabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode(formattedPrice));
}

numPizzaInput.addEventListener('change', onNumPizzaInputChange, false);
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5KMjh/

Comment: It seems to be working exactly as i want to, ill test it first thing tomorrow, but i got 2 go right now. Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand. You saying that you have everything you need, so whats the problem?
The best way it will be placing in `validateForm` something like this:

You are not using php, just js.

```
function validateForm(item){
   //check here if value is number, then:
   var count = item.value;
   var totalPrice = price * count;  //where you have price of this item?
   elementInWhichYouWantToPutTotalPrice.innerHTML("€"+totalPrice);
   ...
```

Comment: i have everyting around it except the code itself to take the value from the input field do it * (value) and then place it in the label

Answer (score 0):

Run a function that changes on `input` event.

```
function validateForm(priceInput) {
  var total = $(priceInput).val() * $('.pricePerUnitNumber').html();
  $('.priceNumber').html(total);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g4hvD/